# jquery .show('slow') direction?

Tags: jquery, show, direction

Is it possible to change direction of `$("selector").show('slow')` and `hide('slow')` effects in jQuery?

I can define directions for other effects such as slide and clip, but there's no option for show or `hide('slow')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`show()` is just an arbitrary function to display an element on a page. Without the argument it wouldn't even have an animation. If you want access to more elaborate animations and control the direction it fades in on you will need to use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Or use an extra library that extends jQuery's native functions like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

`show()` on itself doesn't have any extra effects though..

Comment: .show can be defaulted to a direction (out of the box it is from the right to left)

Answer (score 23):

I can't respond directly to the comments on Norman Joyner's post (not enough rep), but I think you are confused about what 'slow' is. Slow is not an effect like 'slide.' 'Slow' is the speed of the effect. So you should be able to specify

```
$(this).hide("slide", {direction: "right" }, "slow");
```

You can't put a direction directly on "slow."

EDIT:
Oh, I think I know what you are asking. The default effect on "hide" appears to be "blind." According to this - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Blind - the only directions you can specify on blind are horizontal and vertical. Horizontal goes from right to left and vertical from bottom to top. If you want the reverse of those, you'll have to use animate().

Comment: It requires jQuery UI

Comment: .show can be defaulted to a direction (out of the box it is from the right to left)

Answer (score 19):

There are also [**sliding**](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/) jquery effects if you simply want vertical direction:

`.slideDown() .slideUp()` and `.slideToggle()`

Their parameters and usage are almost the same of the `.show()` effect.

Comment: the best answer since it objectively replies to OP problem, without further installing  jQuery UI

Comment: .show can be defaulted to a direction (out of the box it is from the right to left)

Answer (score 4):

You can perform special effects with the `.show()` and `hide()` functions using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/docs/effect/).

Other than that you can use the default `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` or specify a direction for slide in jQuery UI by doing something like:

```
$(this).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: // As I state above, i already know that I can define directions for slide and clip. I need the effect that comes with 'slow'.

Comment: Using 'slow' with the slide effect in any direction? I am confused as to what you are asking.