# how to make the jquery show method appear from the right side than the left side

Tags: jquery

how to make the jquery **show() method** appear from the right side rather than the left side and how to make the jquery **hide() method** to go to the right side rather than the left?.

I know there are some other features like animate and slide out there that could solve this issue. But is it possible to do it with some modifications on the .show() and .hide() method?

Comment: `.show('slide', { direction: 'right' });` with  jQuery UI library

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [jquery .show('slow') direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099191/jquery-showslow-direction)

> show() is just an arbitrary function to display an element on a page.
>   Without the argument it wouldn't even have an animation. If you want
>   access to more elaborate animations and control the direction it fades
>   in on you will need to use .animate()
>
> Or use an extra library that extends jQuery's native functions like
>   jQuery UI
>
> show() on itself doesn't have any extra effects though..

With jQuery UI library you can write:

```
$('.element').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
```